# using message name on message event

Tags: capl

I am trying to declare a message and then use message name in a *on message* event, but I got 
`Expecting message name or identifier` error

my code:

```
variables
{
  message CAN1.foo bar;
}

on message bar //got the error here
{
  //do stuff
}
```

I know I can replace `bar` by `CAN1.foo` in `on message`event, but the location for that message can change depending on the project the capl code runs on. so I want to make it as "general" as possible, so i can only change the part in `variables` when i switch project

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have a "dynamic" `on message` handler.

Your use case could be solved by having a generic `on message *` handler and comparing the message name.

Something like this:

```
variables
{
  char messageName[256] = "foo";
}

on message *
{
  dword context = 0x00010000;
  char buffer[256];
  getMessageName(this.ID, context | this.CAN, buffer, elcount(buffer));

  if(strncmp(buffer, messageName, strlen(buffer) == 0)
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

You have to consult the documentation about the meaning of the second parameter of `getMessageName`, also I am not sure whether `getMessageName` returns `foo` or `CAN1.foo`

Comment: thanks for your answer! :) in the meantime I found another way to do so, using `on message * {
 if(strncmp(this.name, bar.name, 256) == 0) ...` seems shorter and easier to read

Comment: Yes, much better. I did not know that `this.name` was introduced in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Given that dynamic message names are not an option, consider an alternative design.

If `//do stuff` is a function you can re-use, declare it in your main CAPL script or have it included from `doStuff.cin`.

Then, depending on your project, include a `prjMessageEventHandler.cin` that is made of `on message yourProjectDependendMessages` (you can declare lists of messages as well):

```
on message 1,2,3,4
{
    // call to doStuff.cin suitable function
}
```

Since your `prjMessageEventHandler.cin` is that simple, you can have it built programmatically from an xml.

Like this, the only thing you have to change in you CAPL test script is what `prjMessageEventHandler.cin` you want to include.